# Add category uid to news detail

Tags: typo3

I setup a TYPO3 website with News System Ext. and I need to add the category ID to the entry class on the file : `fileadmin\templates\ext\news\Templates\News\Detail.html`

so, the final output will be as follows

```
<div class="entrys category-uid-[id here]"></div>
```

Comment: from the template I see there is something regarding categories already: https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html#L56 - can you make more clear what you need help with? Is it about Fluid in general and how to get that categories into a class= attribute? Please amend your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what I want to do is add a class on the page news detail. currently the default `Detail.html` template is displayed as follows `<div class="entrys">` I want to replace it as follows `<div class="entrys category-uid-21">` 21 is an example uid of a category

Answer (score 0):

There is a little difference if you want just the first category or all categories.

```xml
<f:section name="firstCatClass">
<f:for each="categories" as="category" iteration="iterator"><f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}"> category-uid-{category.uid}</f:if></f:for>
</f:section>

<f:section name="allCatClasses">
<f:for each="categories" as="category"> category-uid-{category.uid}</f:for>
</f:section>
```

then you can insert this in the `class`-parameter of your `div`tag.

```xml
<div class="entrys{f:render(section:'allCatClasses', arguments:'{categories:item.categories}')}">
```

for only the first category there already is a handling in the partial `List/Item.html` which you can modify to:

```xml
<div class="entrys{f:if(condition:newsItem.firstCategory, then:' category-uid-{newsItem.firstCategory}')}">
```